# Can't call a script from within a script

Tags: shell, path, stdin, library-path

I am trying to call a script from within another script.  The idea is that the program should take in email that is sent to it directly from unix mail as stdin, and then parse some stuff out and send it to a new script.

I am having trouble reaching the new script.  However, this problem only occurs when the script is accepting the email directly.  If I cat a file into it, there is no problem and it finds the new script.

IE: if i have a test file called "`email.txt`" and i do the command:

```
cat email.txt | ./receiveEmail.sh
```

then the script calling works fine.

but if `receiveEmail.sh` receives the email directly, it fails to call the new script.  I know this is the point where it fails because I get logs that the script is working all the way up to where it tries to call the new script.

```
--------receiveEmail.sh----------
#!/bin/bash
###do some stuff to parse the stdin coming in and get variable $subject and $body

issue=`. /home/dlaf/bin/makeissue.sh` ->>>> this is the line that doesn't seem to work when the input is straight from the email rather than from a txt file i send it.
```

I am confused why.  I think it might be because I am missing some part of the path?  Maybe the email coming in has no idea what my full path actually is?  Im not sure though because when I type in to the command line `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I just get a blank line, so I assume its not even set so I don't know how this could be a problem

Comment: How you know it's not working? What are you doing in `makeissue.sh`? Try to debug it with some `echo IM IN UR mAKEISSUE.SH` instead of it's content, and see if you get the output.

Comment: i do have echo "im in makeissue.sh" and it never gets in

Comment: Isn't it possible that your program exits before right calling it? (The `echo` in `makeissue.sh` or the sourceing of `makeissue.sh`) For debuggint try calling the script directly (that is in your `receiveEmail.sh` try `/path/to/script` instead of `. /path/to/script`.

Comment: i have an echo line right before the "issue" line that works.  so no reason it should be exiting. also, it works when i send the file in manually, so there is nothing there forcing an exit

Answer (score 0):

When saving output to a variable with Bash, I usually do this

```sh
read issue < <(~/bin/makeissue.sh)
echo "$issue"
```

If the output is multiple lines you can do this

```
read -d'' issue < <(~/bin/makeissue.sh)
echo "$issue"
```

or this

```
mapfile issue < <(~/bin/makeissue.sh)
echo "${issue[@]}"
```